How can I change some value in Mongoose?
I'm trying to find clients by their id and update their name, but i could not successed. I tried every solution on the internet.
Here, i tried findOneAndUpdate() function, i can find by their "_id"s but i can not change the name of a person.
`export const PATCH = async (request : NextRequest) => {    
    try {
        const data = await request.json();
        await ConnectDB();
        const url = request.url;
        const id = url.split('/').pop();
    
        const application = await Application.findOneAndUpdate({_id : id}, {$set: data}, {new: true})

        return NextResponse.json({ application, id, data }, { status: 200 });

    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Application Cannot be updated"}, { status: 401 })
    }
}`


Try logging id and data right before the findOneAndUpdate call.

The update document is to review.
The query in the present form will throw an error shown below.
test> t.findOneAndUpdate({_id : new ObjectId()}, {$set: 'some data'}, {new: true});

MongoServerError: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type string instead. For example: {$mod: {<field>: ...}} not {$set: "some data"}

Please correct it to conform to this form.
test> t.findOneAndUpdate({_id : new ObjectId()}, {$set: {key1: 'some data'}}, {new: true});

Additionally, please make use of the error object in your catch block. At present it has not been referred.
} catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Application Cannot be updated"}, { status: 401 })
    }

